# xsltproc: Can I add breaks (or entities) to --stringparams?

Tags: xslt, entity, libxml2

I am trying to feed xsltproc a stringparam that contains a break... It does not seem to work. Minimal example below.

## Input

This is `bogus.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<this>
  <that/>
</this>
```

This is `test.xsl`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:param name="somestring" select="'here is a&#10;break'"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:message>|<xsl:value-of select="$somestring"/>|</xsl:message>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And this is my command line:
`xsltproc --stringparam somestring 'another string with a&#10;break' test.xsl bogus.xml`

## Output

And the output looks like this:

```
|another string with a&#10;break|
```

The output I want is this:

```
|another string with a
break|
```

Comment: `&#10;` is XML syntax which works inside of XSLT code as it is XML. On your command line I am not sure whether it is possible in XSLT 1.0 to pass in a string with a line break, I think you will need to check documentation of your command line shell whether you can put in a line break there.

Comment: For instance with Windows Powershell the back tick ```n`` can escape a line break  so the command line ``& 'C:\Program Files (x86)\libxml\bin\xsltproc.exe' --stringparam somestring "Another string with `n a line break" sheet.xsl input.xml`` there works for me

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not using xsltproc directly but rather within a more complex toolchain. I have just found that in Bash, `xsltproc --stringparam somestring 'another string with a[now a literal break]break' test.xsl bogus.xml` actually works. In any case, I would prefer an XML-based solution ...

Comment: Well, the escape mechanism for the tool chain or command line processor or shell you use is what you need to find out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using Bash this can be achieved like this:

```
xsltproc --stringparam somestring $'another string with a\nbreak' test.xsl bogus.xml
```

For more information about ansi-c quoting see [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html)